# Only select one checkbox at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this list type menu created using the bootstrap list group. I would like to make only one Main category active at a time. So while "Main Category One" is selected, now if I click the other category "Main category one" will be unselected and "Main category Two" will be activated.

I tried some solutions before asking here but haven't figured it out yet. The list has around 15 Main categories and I just put here the code for only two because the code will be longer otherwise. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

[image]

HTML

```
<a class="list-group-item list-sub-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value='mcat1' id="mcat1" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="mcat1">Main Category One</label>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="list-group-submenu">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pl-5">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value='item1' id="item1" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="item1">Item</label>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<a class="list-group-item list-sub-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value='mcat2' id="mcat2" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="mcat2">Main Category Two</label>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="list-group-submenu">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action pl-5">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value='item1' id="item1" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="item1">Item</label>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Might consider using Radio button versus Checkbox. This is the default nature of Radio buttons. You can use the Click event to clear all checks from elements with id like 'mcat' and then check just the one target. What have you tried so far?

Comment: that is the definition of `radio button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example on how this can be done.  I would advise making it more specific on your lookup for checked checkboxes in the parent container.  I just did a global lookup for this example.

```js
$('.custom-control-input:checkbox').on('change', function(e){
    $('.list-group .custom-control-input').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
      </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a>
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Check this custom checkbox</label>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck3">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck3">Check this custom checkbox</label>
      </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a>
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck4">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck4">Check this custom checkbox</label>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```